# Sum of products of a set of combinations.

Tags: combinatorics

I have a function/algorithm that calculates the sum of the products of unique, order important, combination of a set of parameters.  The set size is $n$, and the number of parameters used in the combination is $n-1$.

These are examples for $n=1$ to $4$

$n = 1, c(n) = 1$

$n = 2, c(n) = x_1 + x_2$

$n = 3, c(n) = x_1\cdot x_2 + x_1\cdot x_3 + x_2\cdot x_3 $

$n = 4, c(n) = x_1\cdot x_2\cdot x_3 + x_1\cdot x_2\cdot x_4 + x_1\cdot x_3\cdot x_4 + x_2\cdot x_3\cdot x_4$

Does anyone know a nice way to write this, mathematically, or could someone point me in the right direction please?

This is the algorithm:

```
  Function CalcC(L,kIn,mIn) Result (numerator)
! Calculates numerator 
    Implicit None ! Force declaration of all variables
! Vars In
    Real(kind=DoubleReal), Dimension(:) :: L
    Integer(kind=StandardInteger) :: kIn, mIn
    Real(kind=DoubleReal) :: numerator
! Vars Private
    Integer(kind=StandardInteger) :: i, j, k, m, n
    Integer(kind=StandardInteger), Dimension(1:(mIn-kIn)) :: combinationSet
    Logical :: loopCombinations
    Real(kind=DoubleReal) :: tempVal
! init
    n = mIn-kIn+1  ! Set size
    m = n-1
    If(n.eq.1)Then
      numerator = 1.0D0
    Else
      numerator = 0.0D0
! Set up starting combination
      Do i=1,m
        combinationSet(i) = i
      End Do
! Loop through all combinations (order important)
      loopCombinations = .true.
      k = 0
      Do while(loopCombinations)
        k = k + 1
        If(k.gt.1)Then
          j = m
          Do i=1,m
            loopCombinations = .false.
            If(combinationSet(j).lt.(n+1-i))Then
              combinationSet(j) = combinationSet(j) + 1
              loopCombinations = .true.
              Exit
            End If
            j = j - 1
          End Do
        End If
        If(loopCombinations)Then
          tempVal = 1.0D0
          Do i=1,m
            tempVal = tempVal * L(combinationSet(i)+kIn-1)
          End Do
          numerator = numerator + tempVal
        End If
      End Do
    End If
  End Function CalcC
```

Comment: These are the [elementary symmetric polyomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) in your variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let the numbers be sampled from a set $S$. I will first create a set $M$ that has the $n - 1$ tuple-multliplied values which will then be summed up into a result set $R$.

$$ 
M = \left \{ \prod_{k = 1}^{n - 1} s_{i_k} : i_k < i_{k + 1}, i_k \in [1, n] \right \}
$$

We setup the numbers $i_k$ such that $i_k \in [1, n]$, and every $i_k < i_{k + 1}$. That way, we get to pick $(n - 1)$ elements out of $S$, in such a way that we are picking all partitions uniquely.

And then the number $r$ as

$$
r = \sum_{m \in M}m
$$

which is the sum of all the multiplied elements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I've used $\sum_{i=1,n} \left( \prod_{j=1,n;i \neq j} x_i \right) $ for my case.  I should have seen it :)